# TypeScript Reassign InputHTMLAttributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

i think i know the answer to this already but i'm effectively trying to overwrite a React `InputHTMLAttribute` when using an interface with `styled-components`

```js
import { InputHTMLAttributes } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

export interface IInputStyles
  extends Omit<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, 'size'> {
  /**  The size of the input */
  size?: 'large' | 'small'
}

export const StyledInput = styled.input<IInputStyles>({}, ({ size }) => ({
  height: size === 'large' ? 48 : 32,
}))
```

i always get `var size: never`

Is there a way to reassign `size` or does that defeat the point of type safety?

"typescript": "^3.9.7",

Answer (score 1):

i believe you cannot overwrite HTML attributes like you want, but what you can do is:

```js
export interface IInputStyles extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  large?: boolean;
}
```

```
export const StyledInput = styled.input.attrs<IInputStyles>((props) => ({
  style: {
    height: (props.large ? "48" : "32") + "px",
  },
}))<IInputStyles>`
  ...other css styles...
`;
```

So, if you create a StyledInput with large attribute, the height should be 48px;

```
<StyledInput large />;
```

else the height should be 32px;

```
<StyledInput />;
```

Comment: Thanks man! yeah i thought that might be the case. The Boolean prop method isn't quite suitable for what i'm trying to do but thanks for the suggestions.

I think the next best thing would be to have an `inputSize` prop of union type `"large" | "small"`